# Getting an my Sql Error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out whats wrong in this code but can't make it work

Could you please help me?

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email); 
$depst = "SELECT dept FROM  stud_reg WHERE email='$email'";     
$colls = "SELECT coll FROM  stud_reg WHERE email='$email'";
$query="SELECT * FROM  stud_reg WHERE coll='$coll' AND dept='$depst'";
$evesel="SELECT id FROM  events WHERE `group`='($depst)' AND coll_id='($colls)'";   
$studsel="SELECT drs_id FROM event_reg WHERE eve_id='$evesel'";
$query="select * from students WHERE nsite_id='$studsel'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Here's the error i am getting

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'k@***.com')' AND coll_id='(SELECT coll FROM stud_reg WHERE email='k@****' at line 1
```

PS- All the tables and rows in this code exits

Comment: First use PDO or mysqli_*, next for debugging do a `echo $query;`

Comment: You better use prepared statements. Error is because of using single quoted string `'$email'` within another single quoted string `'($depst)'`

Comment: You don't appear to be executing the earlier queries at all? Have you looked instead of rewriting the query, perhaps using joins?

Comment: It just the about the `single-quotes` and `double-quotes` problem

Comment: you should place a double quote at email, like this :  `WHERE email="k@****"`

Comment: Well, you're not executing any of the queries above $query. Your SQL error is because the variable "$studsel" is a string, so $query is invalid SQL. Anyway, it looks like you could just write one query joining all your tables together - personally I'd do that, rather than try to run 6 separate queries...

Comment: Thank's for your suggestions ,i am new to mysql and dont ave much experience regarding it.Would take care next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you're trying to run is

```
select * from students WHERE nsite_id='SELECT drs_id FROM event_reg WHERE eve_id='SELECT id FROM  events WHERE `group`='(SELECT dept FROM  stud_reg WHERE email='$email')' AND coll_id='(SELECT coll FROM  stud_reg WHERE email='$email')'''
```

But this is not going to give you what you expect, even if you did fix up the issues with the quoted strings within quoted strings.

I suspect that instead want to combine that all up as joins, so perhaps something a little like:

```sql
SELECT      s.* 

FROM        students AS s

INNER JOIN  event_reg AS er
    ON      er.drs_id = s.nsite_id

INNER JOIN  events AS e
    ON      er.eve_id = e.id

INNER JOIN  stud_reg AS grp
    ON      grp.dept = e.group
    AND     grp.coll = e.coll_id

WHERE       grp.email='$email'
```

As with any syntax error with SQL, when running from PHP, it's best to get the query working in MySQL first, before trying to plug it in to your application.

Answer (score 0):

try like his

```
$query="select * from students WHERE nsite_id='$studsel';";
```

And the first queries are never actually executed, and you seem to overwrite the first $query. Either make a 'join', or use subqueries , something like

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE column1 = (SELECT column1 FROM t2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT id FROM  events WHERE `group`='".$depst."' AND coll_id='".$colls."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message you got, I think it just about the single-quotes and double-quotes problem.
This is the corrected query:

```
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email); 
$depst = 'SELECT dept FROM  stud_reg WHERE email="$email"';     
$colls = 'SELECT coll FROM  stud_reg WHERE email="$email"';
$query="SELECT * FROM  stud_reg WHERE coll='$coll' AND dept='$depst'";
$evesel="SELECT id FROM  events WHERE `group`='($depst)' AND coll_id='($colls)'";   
$studsel="SELECT drs_id FROM event_reg WHERE eve_id='$evesel'";
$query="select * from students WHERE nsite_id='$studsel'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

You must be careful on placing `quotes` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try single query. The problem is quotes in your case.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE nsite_id =
    (   SELECT drs_id FROM event_reg WHERE eve_id = (
        SELECT id FROM  events WHERE
        `group` = (SELECT dept FROM  stud_reg WHERE email = '".$email."')
        AND
        coll_id = (SELECT coll FROM  stud_reg WHERE email = '".$email."')
        )
     )";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
```